# How to compile an installation of Nauty traces?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm installing a program called nauty using cygwin. It starts asking to run using "configure", so far everything has been fine. However, it asks to perform a "make" to compile the installation. I don't know what to write to perform the compilation.

I hope you can help me on what I should write to perform the compilation and finalize the installation. I'm using windows.

Comment: This question seems off-topic here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710209/how-to-run-make-from-cygwin-environment

Comment: On windows machines, where make or gmake are not installed, you can read the Makefile or makefile or gmakefile (and at least in principle) execute the commands in it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The cygwin image is below. When I type make, it doesn't find it in the directory. What should I write on the command line?

[image]